# Highlighted favorite tag question in mobile app

Tags: discussion, feature-request, android-app

[Stack Exchange Application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin&hl=en) for mobile *(For Android Application)* highlighting `favorite tagged` question feature is missing .It is very good feature in browser to identify interesting question .

This is how it looks in browser :
[image]
Should it not be there in **Mobile Application(Android)** also or am I missing something ?

Comment: In the iOS version, there's a very faint blue tint to questions with your favourite tags. Much more subtle than on the web.

Comment: yes sorry to forgot mentioning android application. link is for playstore though. I am updating my question.

Comment: Wait, is this on the mobile web view or the app?  Your tags don't match your question.  Since you have clearly identified the android app, I've retagged your post.  Feel free to correct it if I understood your post incorrectly

Comment: This image is of web . How its looks but same is not having in android application  and thank you for retag @psubee2003